# Как синхронизировать уровень зума google maps и другой картографической системы (не slippy map)

Tags: алгоритм, google-maps, картография

У меня есть морская картографическая система. В качестве проекции - сферический меркатор. Уровень зума - просто некий коэффициент, на который я делю координаты после проекции.
Сейчас хочу интегрировать поддержку google maps в качестве слоя. Соответственно нужна синхронизация. Но проблема в том, что google maps оперирует понятием zoom level, которого нет в моей картографической системе. Необходимо как-то вычислить zoom level, который будет соответствовать уровню масштаба в моей системе. Первая идея, рассчитать текущий meterPerPixel в моей системе, и конвертировать его в zoom_level для google maps. Но я не нашел такой формулы. Есть обратная:

```
auto metersPerPx = 156543.03392 * cos(vp->center_lat* M_PI / 180) / pow(2, m_zoom_level);
```

но как из нее вывести нахождение zoom_level, зная meterPerPixel не могу понять.

Но возможно это и не оптимальный путь, может быть есть какой-то более простой способ синхронизации.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не зная темы и не вдаваясь в подробности могу только помочь решением уравнения относительно
m_zoom_level

```
m_zoom_level = log((156543.03392*cos((vp->center_lat*M_PI)/180))/metersPerPx)/log(2) ;
```